# Setting schema.name in ConsumeKafkaRecord with JsonTreeReader

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to read from Kafka using a `ConsumeKafkaRecord` processor with `JsonTreeReader` as the reader.

I need to set `schema.name` to the schema name in my `AvroRegistry` contoller server.
But how do I do that before reading the data from Kafka ?

I also tried to set `schema.name` to a static value and even tried the `schema.text` property in the reader (with strategy set to read `schema.text`) to the raw schema json, it's still erroring out complaining that it cannot find `schema.name` in the flowfile.

How would I go about using `ConsumeKafkaRecord` with `JsonTreeReader` ?

Comment: What version of NiFi are you using? Also what is the setting of the Schema Access Strategy for your JsonTreeReader? It should match where you want to get your schema from, so "Use Schema Name" will use the Schema Name property (and the registry), "Use Schema Text" will use the Schema Text property, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally if you have a reader with "User Schema Name" then "Schema Name" defaults to "${schema.name}" which means get the schema name from an attribute on the incoming flow file, where the attribute is named "schema.name".

Since ConsumerKafkaRecord (and all other consume Kafka processors) are source processors, there are no incoming flow files with attributes, so you can't reference ${schema.name}. You have to set "Schema Name" in the JsonTreeReader to an actual schema name and not a dynamic value.